# How to search a key word in all columns of big query table?

Tags: google-bigquery, keyword

I'm using the big query to see the data in my google cloud. I want to search a keyword in all columns of a particular table.

Ex: I'm searching for Dubai. I need the result of entries where ever the Dubai word present in any column.

Comment: This looks more like a narrating requirements. Where is your research / code / efforts?

Answer (score 6):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes column names do not contain search word (can be adjusted to address this too)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(TO_JSON_STRING(t)), r'dubai')
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Los Angeles' col1, 'New York' col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Dubai', 'San Francisco' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'atlanta', 'dubai' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'I love Dubai', 'Me too'
)
SELECT *
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(TO_JSON_STRING(t)), r'dubai')
```

Hope above can be good starting point for you to apply to your specific case

But note: cost is scan of whole table - so check cost before running against read (hopefully big) data :o)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It reduced my time and efforts by 10 times.

Comment: @GopiKantamneni - see my comment on your question :o)