# Is it possible to do a full text search in all tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Oracle and SQL Server, it is possible to search all database objects for references of specific text:
SELECT * FROM all_source
WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%blah%'

I would like to do the same thing in Google BigQuery. Is it possible to search every field of every table for a particular value in BigQuery?

Comment: what is the real use case for this to do in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to query multiple tables within a dataset in BigQuery, have a look at [querying multiple tables using a wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). If you would also like to search for a word in all columns of a table (or every table in this case), have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414383/how-to-search-a-key-word-in-all-columns-of-big-query-table) where this topic is discussed.